# Failure in changing node content + JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-events

I wrote this code for create menu with `div` tag

**HTML:**

```
<div id="firstMenuList">
            <div id="firstMenu">choose▼</div> 
                <div id="menulist" class="menulist"></div>    
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
function ccc() {
 
 var id="firstMenu";

 var ar=new Array("hi","there","hello","world");

 var node=document.createElement("div");

 var parent=document.getElementById("menulist");
 
 var nodeData="";

 for (var i=0;i<ar.length;i++)
 {
    var node=document.createElement("div");
    node.setAttribute("id",id+""+i);
    node.setAttribute("class","menulist");
    
    node.setAttribute("onclick","select("+id+""+i+")");
    node.style.top=((i+1)*100)+3+"%";
    node.innerHTML=ar[i];
    parent.appendChild(node);
    
 }
}

function select(id)
{   
 var p=document.getElementById(id);<-this doesn't work on elements that created dynamically
 p.style.backgroundColor="red";
 var t = p.innerHTML;
}
</script>
```

This code creates the menu, but when I click on the menu items code breaks.
The error is:

> "parent is null"

Comment: The _reason_ your code doesn't work is that you have forgotten the inner quotes around the id. This works: `node.setAttribute("onclick", "select('" + id + "" + i + "')");` But use the other solutions posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest to avoid the inline event binding. Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/H4S2f/1/

```
function ccc() {

 var id="firstMenu";
 var cls="firstMenuList";
 var ar=new Array("hi","there","hello","world");
 var node=document.createElement("div");
 var parent=document.getElementById("menulist");
 var nodeData="";

 for (var i=0;i<ar.length;i++)
 {
    var node=document.createElement("div");
    node.setAttribute("id",id+""+i);
    node.setAttribute("class","menulist");
     (function(i) {
         node.addEventListener("click", function() {
             select(id+""+i)
         });
     })(i);
    node.style.top=((i+1)*100)+3+"%";
    node.innerHTML=ar[i];
    parent.appendChild(node);

 }
}

function select(id)
{   
 var p=document.getElementById(id);
 p.style.backgroundColor="red";
 var t = p.innerHTML;
}

ccc();
```

Comment: i don't understand this-> (function(i) {
         node.addEventListener("click", function() {
             select(id+""+i)
         });
     })(i);

Comment: I made this because I needed to keep the value of *i*. I.e. inside the event listener the *i* variable is got from the upper scope. And once the for loop ends the *i* will be the same for all the listeners. That's why I wrap everything inside a closure.

Answer (score 1):

To pass the id to the function you need to ensure that you put quotes around the id:

```
node.setAttribute("onclick","select('"+id+i+"')");
// note the single quotes ----------^--------^
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QK5Wh/1/

But you don't need to use the `id` to get the element when you can pass a direct reference to the element itself:

```
node.setAttribute("onclick","select(this)");
```

And then:

```
function select(p) {   
    p.style.backgroundColor="red";
    var t = p.innerHTML;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QK5Wh/